# Linux rename vlan tagged interface - routes stick around from the old one

Tags: linux-networking

We use a 10Gig NIC with two vlans on it (private network and internet facing), and I am changing the routing on our private network via renaming the network-scripts for it.  This is on CentOS 6.0.

Basically, I took what was eth4.401, renamed it (both the script and interface name inside the script) to eth4.403.  Then I did 'service network restart', and the new interface comes up and I can ping its gateway.  However, both ifconfig and route still show the old interface (eth4.401).  I can do 'ifconfig eth4.401 down' to get it out of ifconfig but the routing table still keeps its directly attached route.  In addition, when running service network restart, I see this error:

```
Bringing up interface eth4.408:  RTNETLINK answers: File exists
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

If I restart, it fixes everything, but any idea on how to get it to drop the old interface (particularly its routes) without restarting the machine?

Answer (score 1):

Your networking scripts are almost certainly calling the [vconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vconfig) command.

To remove a VLAN interface use the command `vconfig rem interface` or `vconfig rem eth4.401`.  This will remove all the associated addresses and routes.

> I can do 'ifconfig eth4.401 down' to get it out of ifconfig but the routing table still keeps its directly attached route

You could run a command like `ip route flush dev eth4.401` and `ip addr flush eth4.401`, to flush all the routes and  addresses associated with an interface without removing it.  But you don't really need to do this in your case.